# Is trigger procedure supported in HSQLDB 2.4.0

Tags: hsqldb

I'm using postgresql dialect with HSQLDB 2.4.0 on a test context.
I'm also using a [trigger procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

When I load my first SQL script into HSQLDB:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE;

CREATE FUNCTION trigg_proc() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test(desc)
  VALUES('hello world');
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TABLE test(
desc CHARACTER VARYING(60) NOT NULL
);
```

I get this error from HSQLDB

```
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: TRIGGER
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: TRIGGER
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsNonCoreReservedIdentifier(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkIsSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTypeDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserRoutine.readProcedureOrFunctionDeclaration(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserRoutine.readCreateProcedureOrFunction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserRoutine.compileCreateProcedureOrFunction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 61 more
```

I would like to know if I'm missing something about the configuration or if HSQLDB does not support trigger procedure.

Comment: Triggers have a completely different syntax in HSQLDB (and it does **not** support PL/pgSQL). See the manual for details: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/triggers-chapt.html  The `SYNTAX PGS` is only a very, very "thin" compatibility layer for a few syntax elements. It doesn't make HSQLDB magically work exactly like Postgre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of triggers in postgres and HSQLDB are not compatible.

For example if you need to creating triggers in HSQLDB, you will write it as something like below

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trigger 
    BEFORE INSERT ON my_table REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN ATOMIC
      BEGIN ATOMIC
    IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
      SELECT my_table_seq.NEXTVAL INTO NEW.id FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
  END;
END
```

Which is quite similar to Oracle trigger syntax.

**Database dialects usually didn't help to perform cross DB PL/SQL operations.**

You should keep this point in your mind.

Wherever you need to perform any database specific functionality , you shouldn't rely on any database dialect but use native queries instead.

Also maintain different native queries for each database you want to use in your application.